# Scroll to element in Iframe not working on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, iframe

I am having the following issue. I have an element located in an Iframe and when clicking on it, it should take me to the top of another element in this Iframe. This works in every browser and on Android but for some reason, it does not work on iPhone.

```
$('#button').on('click touchstart', function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#top-text").offset().top
            }, 1200);

    })
```

Has anyone a solution?

Answer (score -1):

This code is actually a cross-browser solution for making scroll and it works in safari/chrome/firefox

```
$('html,body').animate({})
```

So most likely you are not able to get an element, probably because you are running your code from iframe, you can try it like that

```
$('#button').on('click touchstart', function () {
   $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: 300,
   }, 1200);
});
```

If this will work you can try to catch you element outside of iframe by using something like

```
$(parent.document.getElementById('top-text')).offset().top
```

Comment: Is your #button <a> element?, if so you can also try to add cursor: pointer in css to fix it

Comment: The click is not the issue. When I run the code in the console (while leaving out the click part) it is not doing it either.

Comment: Do you have something like html or  body { height: 100% }? You need to change to html or  body { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }

Comment: Tried that :-).

Comment: Still need an answer here